# Disable <a> click when sorting table

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

```
$("#moduleTable").tablesorter();

<table id="moduleTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="http://google.com">Foo</a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I prevent the anchor click to trigger a redirect to google.com? I cannot change the html structure.

I tried to use somethink like

```
        $("#moduleTable").tablesorter({
            'selectorSort': 'a'
        })  .bind("sortStart",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: why is it an actual link?

Comment: The sort function is working with GET Parameters but in some occasions I have to switch it to a live sorting via tablesorter.

Answer (score 1):

Found an easy working solution

```
            $("#moduleTable").tablesorter({
                initialized : function(table) {
                    $('thead a', table).click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
            });
```